# Mysql query to get closest record

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table

```
id              startmileage       endmileage      price
1                   1                  2             30
2                   2                  3             50
3                   3                  4             70
4                   4                  5             100
5                   5                  25            4.5               
6                   25                 35             7
```

In this table i have stored data to get price between mileages (from start to end mile)
I am able to get the price between 1 difference value like 1 to 2, 2 to 3. But for the values between 5 to 25 and 25 to 35 i have tried a query which will work for both the closest and exact value like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table 
ORDER BY ABS( startmileage - myValue ) 
LIMIT 1
```

But this query only works for one input (startmileage), As i need to use both start and end mileage to get the best closest record.

Can someone please tell me the best query for this ?

Comment: Can you give some expected input/output examples? I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried using MIN(ABS( startmileage - myValue ), ABS( endmileage - myValue )) ?

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM  `cms_farechart` 
ORDER BY MIN(ABS( startmileage - 7 ), ABS( endmileage - 17 )) limit 1
This one is giving syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORDER BY
(
   greatest(startmileage - $myvalue ,0)
   +
   greatest($myvalue - endmileage ,0)
) ASC , startmileage DESC
```

if the $myvalue is within boundaries, this will be equivalent to zero. If it is before startmileage, first part will rose while second is zero. If $myvalue is after endmileage, first part will be zero and second will rose up.

function `greatest( ??? , 0 )` will return `???` only when it is greater then zero, returning zero otherwise.

---

**edit:** A bit optimized query (works the same way):

```
ORDER BY
greatest(startmileage - $myvalue , $myvalue - endmileage ) ASC
, startmileage DESC
```

Comment: It works good with the nearest value but for the exact it is not true like this.
SELECT * 
FROM  `cms_farechart` 
ORDER BY (
GREATEST( startmileage -4, 0 ) + GREATEST( 4 - endmileage, 0 )
)
LIMIT 1

It is returning start mileage = 3 and endmileage = 4.
Where it should be like start mileage = 4 and end mileage = 5

Comment: ductape quickfix: instead of endmileage use (endmileage-0.00001)

Comment: You mean like this? SELECT * 
FROM cms_farechart
ORDER BY (
GREATEST( startmileage -4, 0.00001 ) + GREATEST( 4 - endmileage, 0.00001 )
)
LIMIT 1
This also returns the same record

Comment: The problem was, that end of previous mileage was the same numerical value as start of following mileage. I had to make a difference, a tiny difference.

Comment: Ok, now that I think about it, this solution is better: http://pastebin.com/Ei6cspvK (this simply gives priority for newer mileage if that unsure situacion happens) ; I made an update to my answer.

Comment: Thumbs Up!. Works a great :). Thanks alot David.